# In the Multiresolution Modifier there is a way to save the mutliresolution information, but how do I import and apply the saved *.btx file?

Tags: sculpting

The title says it all really. In the Multiresolution Modifier there is a way to save the multiresolution information. Once I have saved the .btx file what is it for? How do I import and apply the saved *.btx file once I have created it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I know it works is by saving displacements into one .btx file, creating another .btx file on another model and substituting the latter with the former.

1. Save needed sculpt and name the .btx file appropiately ("useful-sculpt.btx").
2. Open new file (or create another model in the same one). On another model add **Multires** modifier and set it to the same level of subdivision.
   *While this isn't necessary in order the method to work it's best to keep the same subdivision level so not to lose any details from the original sculpt*.
3. Save sculpt of second model with *Save External* button to a temporary .btx file (note: do not overwrite the first one).
   *The step is present only to make accessible button for opening a file.*
4. Press small folder icon next to the file name in **Multires** modfiier's properties of the second model to open file browser and choose there file with original sculpt ("useful-sculpt.btx").

   [image: retrieving sculpt from the .btx file GIF]

Comment: Strange. I saved my source .btx file and when importing the .btx to a target mesh of the same subdivision level, not everything matched the source object. Have you experienced that before?

Comment: @BrysonJack It seem to loose details quite noticeable if base shape is different (e.g. cube and cylinder). The result is the same for me if importing on the same shapes (sculpted on cube -> imported sculpt on another cube). Although I think this method isn't very useful as one doesn't have all his models equally shaped from beginning.

Comment: Weird, I used the same shapes...I think I will stick with blend files : )